# Missing Scaffolding Options in ASP.NET MVC 3 Add Controller Dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, scaffolding

I have downloaded and installed the release version of ASP.NET MVC 3 (File version: 1.13.113.0), Created a new project of type ASP.NET MVC 3 web application.

When I right click on Controllers folder=>Add Controller, The Add Controller dialog doesn't have any scaffolding option. It just contains a textbox for Controller name and a checkbox to add action methods for CRUD scenarios.

should I do anything to view the Scaffolding options (Template, Model Class, Data Context Class and View) in Add controller dialog box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Web Platform Installer 3.0 you can find something called "ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update"
Install that one and you get the Scaffolding options and some other stuff.

Comment: It looks like this now is included with VS 2010 SP1. Or, at least, I couldn't find it in the Web Platform Installer, but when I installed SP1 it listed the Tools Update as one of the prereqs it was going to install.

Answer (score 2):

Yes agreed it takes forever to install via web platform installer. Use link http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1491 to download and install.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the lastest with the tool update.

http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update can take a while, but it fixed it for me.

If you tell Web Platform Installer to update Visual Studio it will take basically forever, I had to force shutdown and try again just doing MVC 3.

Thanks Beijer.