# How do I add advanced properties to a controller as seen in the W3 lesson on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble adding a database controller as specified in the W3 lesson [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_models.asp). I am able to set the name of the controller to "MoviesController", but then I have no option for selecting a template, a model class, or any of the options that W3 denotes. ([Image of said issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb97O.jpg))

How might my VS setup be incorrect?

Comment: Did you make a model class and compiled your project?

Comment: I think you should use this url instead: http://www.asp.net/mvc. Just saying...

Comment: @codingbiz, you're definitely right. I'm just trying to get this app up, and I'm running into blocker after blocker.

Comment: @WannaCSharp: Yes, I did. The model class is called MovieDB.cs. I did however run into problems compiling. The `using System.Data.Entity;` reference had errors, so I Googled it. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6048606/689318) very hacky solution which got rid of my errors. 

In brief, problem was the System.Data.Entity was not found, so I went and got a dll from a completely different project, and added that as a reference. This was my first deviation from the W3 lesson.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If not, try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762728/missing-scaffolding-options-in-asp-net-mvc-3-add-controller-dialog

Comment: I did not solve the solution yet. Checking link now.

Comment: @WannaCSharp, Thank you for the link. The link however does not work because my NuGet package manager is too new. I might try installing the new MVC.

Comment: @codingbiz, are you saying that tutorials on [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) are better than those on [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com)?

Comment: Yes. they are better.

Comment: @WannaCSharp, Thanks so much! Doing it now using VS Web Express 2012, and asp.net/mvc tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will help, but you can try clearing your template cache, as show in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496414/asp-net-mvc-3-project-templates-not-showing-up).

If that doesn't work, I suggest reinstalling MVC entirely, its possible that something went screwy and you are missing some packages.

I suggest installing MVC through the Web Platform Installer (WPI), which can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4). It should install everything you need.